# UIAutomation option is not listed in Instrument's list XCode10

Tags: xcode, ios-ui-automation, xcode10.2.1

I want to perform UIAutomation testing on my application and got to know that xcode already provide it in **Instruments**.
but in my xcode UIAutomation option is not available. 
Can any one tell me from where i can get that option or any other way to perform UIAutomation testing on my app?

I am using Xcode 10.2.1

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

UIAutomation is available in earlier Xcode i.e. before 7.3. After Xcode 8 they have provided the UITesting & UnitTesting. If you want to perform UITesting then you can write your test cases there.

Please see below image for your reference.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CK669.png

Comment: Thank you for answering but for UITesting can you please provide/suggest some tutorial or guidance? or any other way that can I use with instruments?